# Locust enforcing exact number of user/s of a specific type

Tags: python-3.x, load, locust

My App has a user, kind of like an admin user, and the app absolutely does not allow more than 1 of that user to be online at a time.  The actions this user performs have heavy implications on the system, so I want every test run with more than a few users to have one of these users present, but my system will crash if more than 1 of these users are booted up.

Is there a way for me to tell Locust to start up exactly 1 and only 1 of a specific user?  My other users are getting booted up fine and they're working as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest solution is to run a separate instance of Locust for just that one user. Then you can do whatever you need to do for all the rest of your users. If you didn't want to split your code, you could use an environment variable or add a custom [command line argument](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.event.Events.init_command_line_parser) that you can key off of to determine which tasks to run.

Another option could be to use the [`test_start`](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=task_set#locust.event.Events.test_start) [EventHook](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html) to kick off a greenlet or thread that runs your admin flow separately and use [`request_success`](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=task_set#locust.event.Events.request_success) and [`request_failure`](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=task_set#locust.event.Events.request_failure) to report request status like a normal task.